# How to play sound when a device is unplugged from USB or audio jack?

Tags: command-line, sound, usb

In need of a software or a command that plays an alarming sound when a device is unplugged from the USB port or audio jack.

Bonus Joke-(Need that for international security purposes)

Comment: A possible approach would be a small script that plays some sound, and then call that script in an Udev rule that reacts to the removal of the device in question. See for example [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-run-a-script-when-usb-devices-is-attached-or-removed-using-udev/). I'm not sure whether Udev manages audio jacks, as well. And if "international security purposes" mean stuff like formal audits, that may well be a whole different can of worms.

Comment: What's your Operating System??

Comment: sir, i am asking on askubuntu so i would surely be on ubuntu

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck understood nothing sir

Comment: Ubuntu manages at least some devices connected to it with a system called [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev). Among other things, you can use so called _udev rules_ to define that a specific command should be executed, every time a specific device is connected to the system or is disconnected from it. So you could write a small script that plays some sound, and have that script execute when the device in question is connected or disconnected. But I don't know whether udev handles the audio jack, and I don't know whether this approach would be secure enough for your purposes.

Comment: thanks sir. would be great if someone gives the commands too as i am not a linux pro....

sad noise.........